# Howto know which name use on given associative array in twig template

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I'm passing the following value to the render method of a Controller class in Symfony2:

```
return $this->render('Bundle:Default:action.html.twig', $things);
```

The associative array $things contains:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => disfraz de reno [kind] => disfraz [description] => Disfraz de reno para ninio de 3-4 anios [own] => 2 [photo] => [age] => [gift] => 0 [published] => 2013-12-25 12:34:09 )
```

When I try to loop through its values this way:

```
{% for row in things %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
    <td>{{ kind }}</td>
    <td>{{ age }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error:

"Variable "things" does not exist in Bundle:Default:action.html.twig at line 23

How should I access the "things" array in twig?

Comment: `$data = array('things' => $things); return $this->render('...', $data);`. TWIG: `{% for row in things %} {{ row.name }} {% endfor %}` Documentation - [Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates) - [Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that you should change in your code. Firstly, the syntax of passing an array to `Twig`, as `lenko` said

```
return $this->render('Bundle:Default:action.html.twig', array(
             'things' => $things
       );
```

Secondly, in the twig, you should iterate the loop in the form of object as following:

```
{% for thing in things %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ thing.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.kind }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.age }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the proper way to send and retrieve object between `Controller` and `View`, twig, in Symfony2.

**EDIT:**
This is the right way to declare the `things` array.

```
$things = array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'disfraz de reno',
                'kind' => 'disfraz',
                'date' => new \DateTime()
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'disfraz de reno2',
                'kind' => 'disfraz2',
                'date' => new \DateTime()
            )
);
```

Comment: First of all thanks, but that said, I tried this way and it doesn't work, I get the following error:

Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a string variable ("4") in Bundle:Default:action.html.twig at line 26.

And the weird thing, is that if I just write "thing" I get all the values...

Comment: So, you might declare your `things` array in the wrong way. See my edited comment.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to pass parameters is:

```
return $this->render('Bundle:Default:action.html.twig', Array('things' => $things));
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew this syntax, but wanted to know if it was possible to do it in a cleaner way.